# Bulk API vs Dataloader

Tags: bulk-api

I have a requirement to send 10 million records to Salesforce from a Mediation System. I can write the records in CSV in the system. Should I upload these files using DataLoader with Bulk API on , or should I make call from Mediation System itself to Call Bulk API Request?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already a CSV file and it is a one time thing then i would indeed use dataloader with Bulk API option on.

It is easy to use and it will go quite fast and if there are any errors you will see it in an error file.

Sven

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for answering. But to add to the question, the requirement is to upload these files automatically , soon after they are created, or to run such process atleast once in a day.

Comment: Well dataloader is a batch tool so you need a PC or a server to run this tool. So if you are ok with that and you can schedule it ones a day then why not. If you have development capacity available and you are able to handle the real time load from your source system then why not. It saves you some maintenance afterwards on the dataloader but it will take some time to build and catch errors if you code it. So it is hard to give you the best solution, it depends on your situation.